# Conditionally wrap code inside view SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to make my code inside a scrollview based on a boolean

Something like this :

```
 ScrollView{
    
          Vstack {
                
         }
         
           Hstack {
           
            }
    
    }.isWrapped(true)
```

So if the bool is true, the content is wrapped inside a ScrollView, if not, I just get the content as is. (without the scrollView parent)

I tried with multiples way, the only thing I see as possible is 2 blocks of code, not good practice thought.

Comment: 2 blocks of code is the way to go, but you should extract the content as a separate view and reuse it in both blocks.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was about to do ,  I just wanted simpler code @SumeshSivan

Comment: Simpler code can be achieved, it just takes a bit more of a compositional approach. Take a look at my answer below as it clarifies two approaches that will make this much more easy to read later.

Answer (score 4):

If your deployment target is iOS 16.0 or newer, you can use [the `scrollDisabled` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/scrolldisabled(_:)) to conditionally disable scrolling.

For older targets, one way to solve this is to always use a `ScrollView`, but tell it not to scroll. If you pass an empty set as the first argument to `ScrollView`, it won't scroll.

```
ScrollView(shouldScroll ? .vertical : []) {
    // content here
}
```

Another way is to extract the content back out of the `ScrollView` in your proposed `isWrapped` modifier, like this:

```
extension ScrollView {
    @ViewBuilder
    func isWrapped(_ flag: Bool) -> some View {
        if flag { self }
        else { self.content }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `isWrapped` modifier looks good. Too bad I can't use it for `NavigationLink`, since it doesn't have the `content` property.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the nature of SwiftUI, you can't remove the parent without removing children. As you mentioned in your edit, this will require two blocks of code. But, you can make it much more friendly in two different ways.

---

The first way is a reusable component. It takes a Binding `isVisible` variable and the content.

```
struct ConditionalScrollView<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding private var isVisible: Bool
    private var builtContent: Content

    init(isVisible: Binding<Bool>, content: () -> Content) {
        self._isVisible = isVisible
        builtContent = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        if isVisible {
            ScrollView { builtContent }
        } else {
            builtContent
        }
    }
}
```

To use this new component is to simply replace the use of `ScrollView` in the area that you want to manually adjust. I.E:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isVisible = true

    var body: some View {
        ConditionalScrollView(isVisible: $isVisible) {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not your only option.

---

If you want to keep things as simple as possible, you can achieve this using a simple `ViewBuilder`. Create the view you don't want to change inside the `ViewBuilder`, and then create a condition around the `ScrollView`, all the while placing the variable as the content. It would look as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isVisible = true

    @ViewBuilder private var mainContent: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }

    var body: some View {
        if isVisible {
            ScrollView { mainContent }
        } else {
            mainContent
        }
    }
}
```

As you've probably come to realize, this is one of the limitations of SwiftUI. But it can be considered a strength because you will always know if a view's parent is there or not.

I hope this little tidbit helped, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it even easier:

```
@State var isWraped : bool = true

var body: some View {
   if isWrapped {
     ScrollView {
          YourView()
     }
       else {
          YourView()
     }
```

Comment: Can you explain what's different between this answer and previous answers, and what any tradeoffs in this approach might be? You say it's easier, but is it functionally equivalent to both previous answers? Why is this easier?

Comment: It's not quite easy if I have more code than just `YourView()`. I would get duplicated code, which is not a good practice.